# Count number of records in MSAccess database excluding NULL VALUE

Tags: ms-access, vb6, count, null

I have a table called call_code..

```
call_id
maintCall_plan
maintCall_unplanned
creditCalls
newBussCalls
phoneCalls
```

What i wanted to do is to count the number of records in maintCall_plan but without counting the null values

here's my code snippet

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim conConnection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

conConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
  App.Path & "\" & "WAR.mdb;Mode=Read|Write"
conConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
conConnection.Open

Dim query As String
Dim recCount As Integer

rs.Open "call_code", conConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
txtmondayplanned.Text = rs.RecordCount
rs.Close
conConnection.Close
End Sub
```

The problem is it is counting all records including null values. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Execute `select count(*) from maintCall_plan where theField is not null`

Comment: sir the table is call_code not maintCall_plan which is a column. I believe that that code will give me an error.. @AlexK.

Comment: So `select count(*) from call_code where maintCall_plan is not null`

Comment: i got it now sir thanks.. 
'Set rs = conConnection.Execute("SELECT COUNT(maintCall_plan) FROM call_code")
    txtmondayplanned.Text = Format$(rs.Fields(0))'